(c++ thread and condition_variable) Could this program never end forever?
I think the source code below may not end forever.
Assume that all waiter threads have entered the wait state.
After that, waker call notify_all()
One thread, t1, wakes up and does something. And Other threads wake up while working, but mutex is occupied by t1, so it returns to the wait state.
That other thread falls asleep forever, so this program doesn't end.
#include <chrono>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

mutex m;
condition_variable cv;

bool isStop = false;

void waiter()
{
    unique_lock<mutex> ul(m);
    cv.wait(ul, []() { return isStop; });

    // ...do something...
}

void waker()
{
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(1));

    unique_lock<mutex> ul(m);
    isStop = true;
    ul.unlock();

    cv.notify_all();
}

void main()
{
    vector<thread> ts;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
        ts.emplace_back(waiter);

    thread w(waker);

    for (auto& t : ts)
        t.join();
    w.join();
}

so I think that waiter function need to Unlock and notify
void waiter()
{
    unique_lock<mutex> ul(m);
    cv.wait(ul, []() { return isStop; });

    // ...do something...

    ul.unlock();
    cv.notify_all();
}

Do you think I'm right?

Neither worker nor waiter should call unlock. Otherwise there is a chance that there's none of conditional variable waiters.

"That other thread falls asleep forever". No. Other threads are blocked on the mutex acquired by the first waiter thread to wake up. Eventually, that first thread will release the mutex, and then some other thread will acquire it. And so they will go and "do something", one by one. Those threads are no longer waiting on the condition variable, so there's no point calling notify_all again.

@igor-tandetnik thank you
i thought a thread go back to wait if fail to lock.
i'm studying c++ concurrency, how can i find details, i couldn't condition_variable specification in c++ refrence

@3CxEZiVlQ
i think waker() need to unlcok
otherwise, After cv.notify_all in waker(), the waiter wakes up but isStop is False, so waiter can go back to wait state again

Reference documentation for std::condition_variable.

waker sets isStop = true; before calling notify_all - so how do you imagine that a thread woken up by notify_all can observe isStop == false?

@3CxEZiVlQ there's no problem calling notify when the mutex isn't locked, as isStop is only modified under the mutex there shouldn't be any race conditions

@3CxEZiVlQ nope, the predicate is checked before starting the wait, as long as the predicate's condition is only changed within the mutex there's no race condition. Notifying with the mutex locked is even recommended against on cpp reference https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/notify_all

FYI, the main function returns an int, always.  This is a value to the operating system to indicate the status of execution of your program.  See also EXIT_SUCCESS and EXIT_FAILURE.

Note that you are kind of "saved" by your 1 second delay. Threads take time to spin up, and be scheduled/woken for the first time. And that order is not deterministic. So if waker would not sleep for one second it could be some waiters have not awoken yet and didn't start waiting yet (but the wakup signal was already given). And yes I have seen that race condition happen in practice.

@PepijnKramer as stated above, there's no race condition, even without the sleep, some threads may never wait at all but none will be left waiting forever

@AlanBirtles You're right, the waiters start first... I stand corrected

@PepijnKramer Even if waker starts first, runs to completion, and terminates before any waiters get to start, the program is still correct. That'd mean that, by the time waiter checks isStop for the first time, it's already true and so the thread never blocks on the condition variable and proceeds straight to "do something".

The original code is correct. When you call notify_all all waiting threads are notified, they'll all attempt to re-aquire the mutex, check the predicate, then continue. This might take a while as only one thread can aquire the mutex at a time but it's guaranteed that all threads will eventually be woken up once the mutex is released. If the thread can't immediately aquire the mutex it'll simply block on aquiring the mutex, it won't re-enter the waiting state without checking the predicate first.
